# Writing on browser with Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, web, driver

I've looked for a solution for 2 days without getting any working answer. That's the point: I made a program which get information from the HTML of a website, needed to make some math calculation in order to resolve a captcha. I tried to make use of the output result with Selenium and everything seems to work perfectly (I handled all the popups, changes of the question and everything). But yesterday my output are not accepted anymore. The website says "Invalid security answer", while my answer it's correct. I think that the browser opened by Selenium has been someway detected but not blocked. So.. Are there any other working ways to write on a browser textbox the result I get from my java program? Or is there a way to try making the Selenium browser more "human"? 
Thank you in advance!

P.S. I'm on Windows 10 with Chrome

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is the whole point of CAPTCHA to check whether the user is a human or a computer.

Your question is proof that the CAPTCHA is working correct to seperate humans from computers, for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

Comment: That's fine. But since my program was working well I don't think that their captcha system works so good. But the point was not the "captcha", I asked if there were other working ways to write on a browser textbox...